# How to block Joomla auto register program?

Tags: php, joomla, spam

My website uses Joomla 2.5, and I received lots of mail spam, because of verification emails (sent by the Joomla website because of spam registrations). Then, my website been suspended by our hosting provider, they said:

> The evidence of the security issue:
>
> sending bulk mail from /home/goodipca/public_html
> Account sending registration spam ~800 in queue, example: 1ZipR5-000zcx-9x-D Hello Collette Valles, Thank you for registering at Sysvideo. Your account is created and must be activated before you can use it. To activate the account click on the following link or copy-paste it in your browser: http://es.goodipcamera.com/index.php?option=com_users&task=registration .activate&token=b7d39e66ab93250e4d852989226a89c0 After activation you may login to http://es.goodipcamera.com/ using the following username and password: Username: collettevalles1 Password: JOyIcn3ZpQ

---

Then, in the "User Manager", I found there are many strange user groups and users:

> |—  Registered-sp-115   8696

But I don't have any user registration and login form in front page!

How can I remove this spam program and clear these spam users?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All users are stored in `users` table in data base, you can delete them froom joomla backend. Although you do not have registration form on your site, there is url for that process `index.php?option=com_users&view=registration` in all joomla sites. 
I suggest you to use captcha for preventing spam registration. If you do not know how to set captcha [here is a tutorial.](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/301-setup-recaptcha-for-joomla)

you can also use online or live email verification system (which is may be paid service). But it will help you solved spam email problems.

Comment: Do not delete users with a "simple query" since there are multiple tables involved.

Comment: Alongwith the url you mentioned, I found 3 more such URLs related to user. As of now, I have blocked them from firewall so that spam registrations will not happen. Alongwith view=registration => view=reset   view=login    view=remind   are three more urls to be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable registration on your Joomla website. See: http://www.itoctopus.com/allow-user-registration-should-be-set-to-no-by-default-on-joomla

This way you will stop receiving spam. The reason why you're getting these registrations despite the fact that you don't have any registration page is because every Joomla website has a "subtle" registration page that can be accessed using the following url: domain/component/users/ (if you are using SEF)

Again, your best option would be to disable registrations altogether.

Answer (score 0):

@ioctopus is completely correct about disabling registration by going to the user manager and changing the option to disallow registration. If you do need public registration you can also set it to require administrative approval and you should turn on captcha.

However, if you have new user groups that is a completely different situation.  Only someone with super admin privileges can create a new group (unless you have installed some component that allows other people to do it). That means you have been hacked, someone who you don't know has administrative access to your website.  You need to proceed as if you have been hacked, starting with checking any extensions you have installed against the vulnerable extensions list and continuing from there (information on recovering from hacking in on the docs.joomla.org.

Create a new superadmin user for yourself and block and delete every other user.  In particular check to see if any of the new users has been given admin access.

Comment: thank you. I checked the database user table, I found there is new one administrator "admin2", but I remember I never created this one. I have disable registration and deleted all spam users from database, but I want to know the problem is from hacking or Trojans extensions or codes, if I can't find the real reason, the problem could take place again.

Comment: Okay so you need to go read the documentation on recovering. First find out if you have an extension installed that caused this by checking the vulnerable extensions list. Also are you on an up to date version on Joomla?